# HTML5 Websocket wait for connection and readystate change before sending message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I am using Websockets in my React app, and I have to connect to a web socket and then sent a message as soon as it gets connected. but my code do not works in sync

Here it is

```
ws = new WebSocket(uri);
ws.send('my msg');
```

Is there a way to wait for connection established and ready state changed!
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#example):

> ```
> // Create WebSocket connection.
> const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
>
> // Connection opened
> socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
>     socket.send('Hello Server!');
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the following to prepare my WebSocket for use in many other places, *not just immediately* after the WebSocket readyState changes:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep
const sleep = (ms) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

// (inside of async function)...

  const ws = new WebSocket(<webSocketServerUri>);

  let timeToConnect = 0;
  while (ws.readyState !== ws.OPEN) {
    await sleep(1);
    ++timeToConnect;
  };

  console.log('The WebSocket took ' + timeToConnect + ' milliseconds to connect.');

// (inside of async function)...
// ...
// (some other place in the code where 'ws' is accessible)...

  ws.send('my msg');

// (some other place in the code where 'ws' is accessible)...
```